# Case of Pronoun

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, whom

I want to know **_** you talked to.  (who or whom)

I want to know **_** the culprit is.  (who or whom)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=who+vs+whom&oq=who+vs+whom&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2489j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Use of whom is [infrequent and declining](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who%2C+whom&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Do you suppose this is because ignorance of grammar is on the rise, or have I been lied to about the rules for who vs whom?

Comment: @Lumberjack: Possibly, or maybe shifting fashions and/or a desire to avoid sounding stuffy and old fashioned. See *[Whom do you trust?](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2012/04/grammar)* Wikipedia says *"According to Mair, the decline of whom has been speeded by the fact that it is one of relatively few synthetic (inflected) remnants in the principally analytical grammar of Modern English."*

Comment: Interesting read.  Thank you!  I vote that we just kill whom once and for all and call it a day.

Comment: @Lumberjack: Probably both. Certainly, knowledge of English grammar among English speakers is almost nonexistent, and, equally certainly, you have been lied to about English grammar if you were educated in an Anglophone school.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It's declining, but one still can't go so far as to use _who_ after _to_.

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to know ---- you talked to*. (*who* or *whom*?)
>   *I want to know --- the culprit is*. (*who* or *whom?*)

The simple answer is:

- Always use *who*. Never use *whom*.

I.e, *who* works, and is natural and grammatical in **both** of the example sentences.

- *I want to know who you talked to.*
- *I want to know who the culprit is.*

This is what most native English speakers would say.

However, if you are bound and determined to use *whom*,
whether you understand the rule for using it or not,
(and if you did understand the rule, you wouldn't have asked the question)
then you should know that

*whom* **can** be used in the first sentence

- *I want to know whom you talked to.*

but *whom* **can't** be used in the second sentence

- **I want to know whom the culprit is.*
  (that's what the asterisk in front of the sentence above means -- it's ungrammatical).

Answer (score 1):

An easy rule to remember is: Use 'who' whenever you would use 'I/he/she' (subject) and use 'whom' when you would use 'me/him/her' (object):

> I want to know **whom** you talked to 
>   You talked to **me**

And conversely:

> I want to know **who** the culprit is 
>   **He** is the culprit

As mentioned numerous times in this forum, the use of 'whom' is gradually declining. But it's always good to know the right way.

Comment: Are you saying that Professor John Lawler is wrong then when he says '... who works, and is natural and grammatical in both of the example sentences.' ?

Comment: @Edwin, Eric's suggested way of differentiating is useful, although it would perhaps have been better to make it clear that this is a way to ascertain when you **could** use _whom_, rather than baldly stating: _Use whom when ..._ .  There are, in fact, written contexts when using _whom_ is a small courtesy to the reader. If a sentence starts: _The candidate who ..._ I momentarily expect the candidate to be the subject of the following relative clause. If the sentence continues _The candidate who Obama appointed ..._, then my expectations are confounded.

Comment: [cont] This is not usually a big deal, but in some contexts (e.g. application letters), the reader may react negatively.